# CS50 - speller - All words Misspelled - debug shows cursor to be NULL, why?

Tags: c, nodes, spell-checking, cs50

I'm doing the CS50 Speller problem set. Upon executing my code, all words loaded from the textfile are shown as "Misspelled".

Debugger: upon entering the while loop, my cursor becomes NULL, and thus, immediately breaks out of the while loop.

I ran Valgrind, and there are no memory leaks. Debug50 seems to indicate that the index is correct, but upon entering the while loop, cursor becomes NULL.

The problem must be somewhere in the bool check() function.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents number of buckets in a hash table
#define N 26

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
 {
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
 }
 node;

// Represents a hash table
node *hashtable[N];

// Hashes word to a number between 0 and 25, inclusive, based on first letter
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
   return tolower(word[0]) - 'a';
}

// initialize words counted in dictionary to 0
int words_counter = 0;
bool loaded = false;
node *head;

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{

    // Initialize hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }

    // Open dictionary
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        unload();
        loaded = false;
        return false;
    }

    // Buffer for a word
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Insert words into hash table
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        // TODO
        //malloc new node * for each new word,
        // node *head = malloc(sizeof(node));
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

        // Check if pointer returns NULL
        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return false;
        }

        //if malloc succeeds copy word into node
        strcpy(new_node->word, word);


        //Insert the node into linked list, starting at head

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = new_node;
            words_counter++;
        } else {
            new_node->next = head;
            head = new_node;
            words_counter++;
        }
    }

    // Close dictionary
    fclose(file);

    // Indicate success
    loaded = true;
    return true;

    }
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int index = hash(word);
    node* cursor = hashtable[index];

    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

```
// Implements a spell-checker

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: speller [dictionary] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    for (int c = fgetc(file); c != EOF; c = fgetc(file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);

    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}

// Returns number of seconds between b and a
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                 ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

```
// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful 
bool unload(void)
{
// TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = hashtable[i];
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            node *temp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(temp);
        }    
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
// Dictionary.h - Declares a dictionary's functionality

#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

#include <stdbool.h>

// Maximum length for a word
// (e.g., pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)
#define LENGTH 45

// Prototypes
bool load(const char *dictionary);
unsigned int size(void);
bool check(const char *word);
bool unload(void);

#endif // DICTIONARY_H
~~~
```

Comment: Where is `main` declared?

Comment: Welcome to [SO], please provide a complete [mcve]. Right now it's not easy to test your program. Also provide a sample of "dictionary"

Comment: Thank you for the notes, I've added the 'speller.c' along with the header file, dictionary.h script to this post. Main is declared in speller.c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `check` function uses `hashtable` to find the linked list of words from the dictionary that have the given hash. However, you don't have any code that puts the loaded dictionary of words into `hashtable`.

You either need to do that during `load` (this is likely, as `load` initialises `hashtable` to nulls), or add an extra step that takes a loaded dictionary puts it into the hashtable.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply. This really helped!
I assumed the problem was in my 'check' function as my dictionary loaded properly. I'm new to C, so I had to think about how to put words into the hashtable but figured it out, thanks to your comment.